# passing data to an action creator and returning a property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm looking to pass data from one API get request to another. The property I want to pass is an ID that the first property my API returns. With this property I want to inject the ID into the second API call to specifically call an object. This endpoint will return a ClickUrl. I would like to return this URL and inject it into a Link href in my view.

Below is my view in which I map over an array that houses my first api call. I want to pass promo.merch_id back into the second api call and return a value of ClickUrl.

```js
class AZFeatStores extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPromo();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getPromoLink(merchantID) {
    this.props.fetchPromoClick(merchantID);
  }


  renderMerchPromo() {
    if(!this.props.promos) {
      return <div>Loading... </div>;
    }
    else {
      return this.props.promos.map((promo) => {
        return (
          <div className="feat-inner col-md-3" key={promo.promotion_id}>
            <div className="merch-img">
              <img src={promo.image_125} alt="merch-img"/>
            </div>
            <span className="cash-back">{promo.final_rebate} Cash Back </span>
            <Link to="This is where I want to inject the URL" className="shop-now">Shop Now</Link>
            <a href="#" className="learn-more">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="col col-md-12">
        { this.renderMerchPromo() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { promos: state.promos.all};
}


export default connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchPromo })( AZFeatStores );
```

My action creator

```js
export function fetchPromo() {

  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/promos/${PROMO_ID}/ptypes/${PTYPE}`, {
    headers: headers
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_PROMOS,
    payload: request 
  };
}

export function fetchPromoClick(merchantID) {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/getclick/${merchantID}`, {
    headers: headers
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_PROMO_LINK,
    payload: request 
  };
}
```

My Reducer

```js
import { FETCH_PROMOS, FETCH_PROMO_LINK } from '../actions/promotions';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [] ,promo: null }; 

export default function ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROMOS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data.method_response.promos.merch.partner };
    case FETCH_PROMO_LINK:
      return { ...state, links: action.payload.data.method_response };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm new to this so don't hate to hard on my code :)

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue with the given solution? Or do you need some more help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may wait till the promise for the first API call gets resolved, then call the second API with the response of the previous API call. Finally return the promise of the second invocation like this. You just need to chain the API calls here since they are dependent on one another.

```
export function fetchPromo() {

  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/promos/${PROMO_ID}/ptypes/${PTYPE}`, {
    headers: headers
  }).then(response => {
    // Extract your ID value here.
    // Then call the second endpoint with that ID value.
    return axios.get('/user?ID={response.id}');   // using response.data
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_PROMOS,
    payload: request 
  };
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: Been away so I'm trying it now. To extract the ID from the first get request, can I use "payload.data" to retrieve it?   

So like `var merchID = payload.data.method_response...etc`

Comment: access it using the response.someProp